# Prononciation particulière du déterminant démonstratif, « C'te gars » [stəga] : ailleurs qu'à Paris et au Québec ?

Tags: prononciation, démonstratifs, déterminants

Le sujet<sup>1</sup> est celui de la prononciation du [déterminant démonstratif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4332) *ce (masc. sing. avec cons.) / cet (masc. sing. avec voyelle, avec exceptions) / cette (fem. sing.) / ces (pluriel)* dans certaines situations. Dans *certains cas*, soit en fonction de règles de phonétiques (1), soit, dans la langue plus populaire, selon que le mot qui suit commence par une voyelle phonétiquement (2)(3), soit, de manière encore plus populaire, quand le mot suivant commence par une consonne (4) ; dans ces cas le *e* du déterminant peut être affaibli ou devenir muet :

> (1) ce matin [smatɛ̃] 
>  (2) cet homme [stɔm] 
>  (3) cette affaire [stafɛr]
>   
>  (4) cette femme [stəfam ; le premier *e* de *cette* tombe]

Historiquement, on a un exemple usuel de ce genre de prononciation avec *à cette heure* : *asteure* (Queneau) ; *asteur* (A. Maillet).<sup>2</sup>

---

**Au masculin, devant une consonne**, comme on l'a vu dans (1), c'est normalement le [s] qui reste quand le *e* de *ce* s'amuit (5A). On a un phénomène particulier à [Paris](https://archive.org/stream/LeLangagePopulaire/Le_langage_populaire#page/n99/mode/2up/search/chien) et au [Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#D.C3.A9monstratifs)<sup>3</sup>, **notamment**, où on a semble-t-il aussi dans ce cas familièrement [stə] (5B), comme dans (4) (féminin + cons.) :

> (5A) C'chien [sʃjɛ̃] 
>   (5B) Çte (c'te/ç'te) chien [stəʃjɛ̃]

Si on ajoute aussi une **interversion** (6C ; *ce* « à l'envers »), qu'on utilise un nom plus usuel (gars) et qu'on renforce avec l'adverbe (là), on obtient :

> (6A) C'gars-là [sɡa-la]
>  (6B) C'te gars-là [stəga-la]
>  (6C) Ec gars-là
>   [əsga-la]

*Question* :

1. Est-ce qu'on entend 6B (sans adverbe) familièrement ailleurs qu'à Paris et au Québec ?
2. Lequel des trois utilise-t-on le plus couramment ?
3. Entend-on aussi (6C) ?

... et où ?

---

<sub>1. La présentation du sujet suit celle du §615 dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*).</sub> 
<sub>2. Graphies basés sur anciennes formes étayées au *FEW/Wartburg* ([*astheure*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/20185) : maintenant etc., chez Henri IV, Montaigne ; en picard, normand, wallon etc.).</sub>
<sub>3. Quelqu'un qui ne sait pas (comme moi) aurait pu penser qu'il s'agissait de phénomènes de [*métathèse/interversion*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=metathese&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) (c-et/c-te) avec (2) ; mais avec ce masculin+consonne (Paris-Québec) (1), c'est *ce*, un son est ajouté pour obtenir [stə], et ça ressemble ainsi davantage à l'[épenthèse](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=%C3%A9penth%C3%A8se&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), un sujet [intéressant](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1650&context=pwpl).</sub>

Comment: Pour la Belgique : A est familier;  B est très rare ; C jamais entendu

Comment: Est-ce que les formes en stə devant consonne ont la même valeur sémantique/pragmatique que les formes en sə ?

Comment: @GAMPUB je dirais que B a une connotation un peu "méprisante"

Answer (score 3):

En Suisse, on entendra fréquemment 1, 3, 4 et 6A, parfois 2, 5A et 6B (voir ci-dessous), jamais 6C.

Concernant 5B/6B, la connotation est selon moi négative, voire péjorative.

Par exemple on dira volontiers:

> - C'te chienne de vie !
> - Fais pas c'te tronche !
> - Oublie c'te phrase ! (si on a dit quelque chose qu'il ne fallait pas...)
> - Qu'est-ce que tu pense de c'te connerie ?
> - Je ne l'aime pas, c't espèce de débile !

Cette forme est utilisée pour remplacer `cet` ou `cette` mais pas pour remplacer `ce`. Donc dans le cas d'un mot masculin, uniquement si le mot commence par une voyelle.

C'te gars (Ce gars), sonne faux. C't idiot (Cet idiot), sonne juste.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rappel court

Je me concentre sur les trois formes suivantes :

> (6A) C'gars-là [sɡa-la]
>   (6B) C'te gars-là [stəga-la]
>   (6C) Ec gars-là [əsga-la]

#### Sources de cette réponse, localité

Aucune source, si ce n'est le vécu.

J'ai toujours vécu dans l'Est de la France (Lorraine). Je travaille au Luxembourg et côtoie à ce titre des belges francophones dans le domaine professionel.

#### 6A

6A correspond pour moi à une simple élision du E. Elle s'entend à titre familier, avec ou sans adverbe (je n'envisage l'utilisation de l'adverbe qu'à titre démonstratif : « C'est c'gars-là, pas un autre. »).

#### 6B

J'ai employé cette forme (sans adverbe) à l'époque du lycée (2000-2003), souvent sous forme exclamative sans verbe (« C'te gars ! » dans le sens de « Comme il est/Ce qu'il se permet/Ce qu'il ose ! »).

Je ne crois pas l'avoir utilisée et rarement entendue depuis.

#### 6C

Je pense l'avoir entendue, peut-être utilisée, à l'époque du lycée également, peut-être à titre sarcastique/parodique.

Elle est cependant très rare dans ma région. Il me semble que cette prononciation correspond plutôt au Nord de la France, mais je n'ai aucune source pour étayer cette information.

Dans tous les cas, cette forme me semble très régionale.

#### Fréquences relatives

6A >> 6B > 6C

---

<sub>Cette réponse est une version détaillée et mise en forme du commentaire initialement posté puis supprimé pour éviter les doublons et la pollution.</sub>