# How do I say "A la suite de cet incident"

Tags: prononciation

I want to say: "*A la suite de cet incident*" in French
In theory, we need to say: \a la sɥi**t də** sɛt ɛ̃ si dɑ̃\

However, it is very difficult to pronounce the two sounds \t də\ of the two words "*suite de*".

I heard somewhere that we must (or we should?) replace \t də\ by \tə\  (or \t, I don't know).
So, we say \a la sɥi **tə** sɛt ɛ̃ si dɑ̃\

Could you please confirm whether this replacement is correct or not?

Comment: « À la suiteu deu cèt'īncident » — oralement on entend souvent : « À la suit' de cét-incident »

Comment: @Personne Donc, d'après vous, on prononce tous \t də\ ? Je me rappelle, dans un cours de phonétique que j'ai il y a très très longtemps, le prof m'a dit que, pour la phrase "il a un coup de foudre" => / il-a un cou t fou dre/  (on ne prononce pas le mot "de", ni la conconne "p")

Comment: Canadian French speakers will say this differently from mainland French speakers. :)

Comment: @Lambie My teacher is mainland French. I would like to know how mainland French say this phrase, and also the phrase "il a un coup de foudre" :)

Comment: What is troubling you about coup de foudre??///try à la sweet + de [finish the t sound THEN do the de] so the parse is: à la suite/de/cet incident, where suite and de sound almost together. It shouldn't be hard to do the ending t sound followed by de.

Comment: @Lambie Yes I see now, in fact, I think I can pronounce "il a un coup de foudre" no problem. But yesterday I found my note of the pronunciation course I took a long time ago, and in the note, I had written that / il-a un cou t fou dre/ (on ne prononce pas le mot "de", ni la conconne "p").

Comment: @Lambie Un coup de foudre est toujours troublant !

Comment: @Lambie Not clear whether you're reacting to Personne's comment or if you're talking about _à la suite de cet incident_ or _coup de foudre_, or lexicon, turn of phrase, pronunciation? You could hear OP's sentence in Canada, as well as a discussion about a _coup de foudre_. That being said a pronunciation similar to _à la suite de c't'incident_ or _coup d'foudre_ is not something peculiar to Canadian French, generally that's just popular language. See for instance [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/15937/26366) for more. Please when you say sth. is different or wrong, say what you mean.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa My comment is clear. I have three slashes after coup de foudre, which signals another topic follows it, And then I give my take on "à la suite de". I can record the difference but don't know how to IPA it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we have trouble chaining [d] and [t] (like in "bedtime") but if pronounced quickly, the sentence will sound like: \a la sɥitsɛt ɛ̃sidɑ̃\

This is called ***[assimilation régressive de voisement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phon%C3%A9tique)#Assimilation_r%C3%A9gressive)***, for example observed with the word *médecin* where the drop of the schwa leads to \metsɛ̃\

Comment: Ça c'est mal parler.

Comment: @LPH L'OP s'intéresse au français tel qu'on le parle, pas à des jugements de valeur décorrélés de la réalité.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci de votre réponse. Pour la phrase "il a un coup de foudre", est-ce que vous pensez qu'on dit / il-a un cou t fou dre/ (on ne prononce pas le mot "de", ni la conconne "p")  (J'ai fait ce cours de phonétique il y a très longtemps donc peut être ce que j'ai rappelé n'est pas correct)

Comment: @NN2 On ne prononce jamais le *P* de *coup*. Le /d/ peut effectivement muter en /t/ en cas de liaison entre *de* et le mot suivant.

Comment: @jlliagre Je vois, je vous remercie. Est-ce que vous rappelez le nom de cette règle "muter en /t/ en cas de liaison"?

Comment: Il y a aussi l'élision du _e_ de [_de_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99#Fran%C3%A7ais) dans le parler populaire qui peut donner un résultat semblable avec _coup d'foudre_ ; ou est-ce ce même enchaînement ? Une autre question !

Comment: @NN2 J'ai parlé par erreur de liaison mais il s'agit ici d'un enchaînement puisque seules des consonnes sont concernées.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai trouvé un exemple (dans l'article que vous avez mentionné) qui répond bien à la question "coup de foudre":  "des rouleaux de soie, [deʁulodəswa] → [deʁulod̥swa] (ou [deʁulotswa]) : assimilation régressive de la surdité de [s] par [d] après élision de [ə]."

Answer (score 1):

1/ Right:  \a la sɥit də sɛt ɛ̃ si dɑ̃\
2/ Never said: \a la sɥi tə sɛt ɛ̃ si dɑ̃\

There has to be a d in the pronunciation. It is not difficult at all, at least for the French, and so, after some practice it should also be easy for foreign learners.  The \ə\ in "sɥit də sɛt" is often (specially when speaking fast) barely heard, but it must figure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!